# How to format raster legend in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Using QGIS 2.0, I have created a color legend for raster values in the print composer. By default each color swatch appears to the left of its label in the legend but I want the color swatchs to appear to the right of their labels. I'd also like to be able to specify how the items are aligned with the legend's frame (e.g. right/left). I've looked in the item properties for the raster legend in the print composer, but haven't found any controls to effect this behavior.

Comment: I suppose you should just export your map and drag swatches to the left in the external image editor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can swap which side of the swatches the labels appear on, even in QGIS 2.0 and I also don't think there is any control for justification of the labels.  However, a very crude work-around could be to create two legends side by side, with one overlapping the other.  Then blank the swatches on the left-hand one with an opaque but borderless rectangle.  You will then have left-justified text to the left of the swatches (from the second legend).